# Shortening subclause with "bien que"

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

> Bien qu'il soit cher, ce piano est d'excellente qualité.

Is it possible to shorten this sentence to the following?

> Bien que cher, ce piano est d'excellente qualité.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence would totally be correct this way. Although, you will probably see the first sentence more often than you will see the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, the slight difference is that the second sentence is a bit less casual.